# T-SQL - How come changing the order is giving me an error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was working on the T-SQL code. I was getting error when I changed the order of the WHERE clause. The second code is giving me an the this error

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

I don't understand the logic behind this. I would appreciate any help on this.

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, Name, ListPrice
FROM 
    SalesLT.Product
WHERE 
    ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
                  FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
                  WHERE UnitPrice < 100)
    AND (ListPrice > 100)   
ORDER BY 
    ProductID;
```

VS

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, Name, ListPrice
FROM 
    SalesLT.Product
WHERE 
    ProductID IN (ListPrice > 100) AND (SELECT ProductID 
                                        FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
                                        WHERE UnitPrice < 100)      
ORDER BY 
    ProductID;
```

Comment: What is an error? This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Please read about [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Comment: MegaTron, I added the error on the question. Thanks!

Comment: ListPrice is from Product table

Comment: So, the second query is completely wrong. It can't works, Please check if you proper copied and pasted here the first one

Comment: The second code is working.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your issue, this is not a valid TSQL WHERE clause

```
WHERE ProductID IN (ListPrice > 100)
```

What you probably wanted is this:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, ListPrice
FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE ListPrice > 100 
AND ProductID IN (
    SELECT ProductID 
    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
    WHERE UnitPrice < 100
)
ORDER BY ProductID;
```

Comment: OP says that "The first code is giving me an the this error" but not the second. You are right but the problem in the first one

Comment: I cannot see how the first query is giving him an error, I am assuming he meant the 2nd query is giving him an error.

Comment: @MegaTron, apparently, OP has made a mistake/mistyped in the question. His first query is fine, second is not correct.

Comment: Yes, I also cannot see how the first query is giving him an error

Comment: @VladimirBaranov but did you see a new comment? "The second code is working...." But  how???? I do not understand anything now :)

Comment: Sorry guys. I made an error. First code is fine. The second is giving me an error. I made the mistake.

Comment: @blackknight316 of course the second is giving an error. It can't works. As I said read about [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The first query looks syntactically valid and should not give any error, unless the referenced column ListPrice belongs to some other table and not SalesLT.Product.

Your first query has two predicates which both are valid as they evaluate to true/false:

```
ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
    WHERE UnitPrice < 100)
```

and

```
(ListPrice > 100)
```

in your second query you didn't change the order of the predicates, but your change made the syntax invalid as the predicates must evaluate to a boolean value, which neither:

```
ProductID IN (ListPrice > 100) 
-- IN (true/false) is meaningless. IN needs a list of some sort.
-- (ListPrice > 100) returns true/false, not a list of ProductIDs
```

or

```
(SELECT ProductID FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail WHERE UnitPrice < 100) 
-- this returns a list of values, not a true/false value
```

does. The problem is that you broke the predicate in half at the wrong place.

If you want to change the order of the predicates it should look like this:

```
WHERE (ListPrice > 100) -- the parentheses are not needed here, only cosmetic
     AND  
     ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail
    WHERE UnitPrice < 100)
```

but know that the order should not matter, although it might be evaluated from left to right there's a good chance that the query optimizer will evaluate all predicates in such a way that the best solution is chosen regardless of the order.

Comment: I am not understanding my friend Bender!